# Nginx is not working as reverse proxy for .net core 6 web API deployed on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, nginx, .net-6.0

I am following MSDN tutorial for deploying .net core 6 app on Ubuntu 20.04 server with nginx as reverse proxy. App is working fine locally in the server I am getting the response; but when I run http://localhost; I was expecting that nginx will get the request and redirect to http://localhost:5000; but I am getting "curl: (52) Empty reply from server";

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
```

- TCP_NODELAY set
- Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
- GET / HTTP/1.1
- Host: localhost
- User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
- Accept: */*
- Empty reply from server
- Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
  *curl: (52) Empty reply from server

What am I doing wrong ?
Nginx Sites-available default setting with single server:

```
    server {
        listen        80;
        server_name   example.com *.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
```

Lunch Setting file:

```
"profiles": {
"APIHostedonLinux": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "dotnetRunMessages": true,
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "swagger",
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
```

Program file:

```cs
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});

//app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: nginx should have a root path routing to `/`, other proxied services should be mapped to other path, such as `/aspnetcore`

Comment: Note that launch settings file is used only for local development environment and is not published/deployed automatically.